# Repeating lines of code

Tags: java

For my school project I have to make 9 simple cyclops faces in Java. At the moment I am finished but I am not satisfied with the repeating lines of code. Is there a way to change this to fewer lines of code?

```
public void paint(Graphics tekening){
    int i, xbegin, ybegin;
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        //Text
        Font font = new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 20);
        tekening.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        tekening.setFont(font);
        tekening.drawString("VIERKANTEN CYCLOOP", 250, 30);

        //Backgroundcolor
        tekening.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        tekening.fillRect(100, 50, 500, 500);

        //Faces
        tekening.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

        tekening.drawRect(150, 100, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(300, 100, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(450, 100, 75, 75);

        tekening.drawRect(150, 250, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(300, 250, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(450, 250, 75, 75);

        tekening.drawRect(150, 400, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(300, 400, 75, 75);
        tekening.drawRect(450, 400, 75, 75);

        //Eyes
        tekening.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        tekening.fillOval(175, 120, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(325, 120, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(475, 120, 20, 10);

        tekening.fillOval(175, 270, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(325, 270, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(475, 270, 20, 10);

        tekening.fillOval(175, 420, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(325, 420, 20, 10);
        tekening.fillOval(475, 420, 20, 10);

        //Pupils
        tekening.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        tekening.fillOval(181, 121, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(331, 121, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(481, 121, 6, 6);

        tekening.fillOval(181, 271, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(331, 271, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(481, 271, 6, 6);

        tekening.fillOval(181, 421, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(331, 421, 6, 6);
        tekening.fillOval(481, 421, 6, 6);

        //Mouths
        tekening.setColor(Color.RED);

        tekening.fillArc(171, 145, 25, 3, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(321, 145, 25, 3, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(471, 145, 25, 3, 180, 180);

        tekening.fillArc(171, 295, 25, 7, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(321, 295, 25, 7, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(471, 295, 25, 7, 180, 180);

        tekening.fillArc(171, 445, 25, 11, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(321, 445, 25, 11, 180, 180);
        tekening.fillArc(471, 445, 25, 11, 180, 180);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example of how to simplify one of the section, I hope it is useful.

```
//Faces
tekening.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
for(int var = 100; var <= 400; var += 150){

     for(int var2 = 150; var2 <= 450; var2 += 150){

          tekening.drawRect(var2, var, 75, 75);
     }
}
```

You can get the same result just adding a bit more of code for Mouth

```
//Mouths
tekening.setColor(Color.RED);

int second_parameter = 145;
int increment = 150;

for(int var1 = 3; var1 <= 11; var1+= 4 ){

    for(int var2 = 171; var2<=471; var2+=increment){

        tekening.fillArc(var2, second_parameter, 25, var1, 180, 180);

    }
    second_parameter+=increment;
}
```

Comment: How would I do the Mouths? The arc has 3 different sizes.

Comment: There is no var in my eg.: for(int var2 = 171; var<=471; var+=increment){

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake! Fixed

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend going with an object based approach to this, for example:

```
public class Face {
     private int x;

     /** A little light on parameters but you get the idea. **/
     public Face(int x) {
         this.x = x;
     }

     public void draw(Graphics g) {
         // Use graphics to draw a face.
     }
}
```

Then you end up with a parent draw function like:

```
Face face = new Face(10);
face.draw(tekening);

Face face2 = new Face(20);
face2.draw(tekening);
```

Cuts out the repeating code. Cleans up your logic and means you can handle each component piece directly, without some procedural style script to edit.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the draw method means it would have to know if it was drawing a rect or oval, so some abstraction might be in order.

Comment: Surely that would be an implementation based decision? Pupils draw circles, faces draw rectangles etc. We make classes for the different areas of the face? You could make a full object relationship tree. A Face object contains two Eye objects which each contain a Pupil object etc. It's very representable using OO techniques.

Comment: that is a good point, and it might be for the implementation at hand the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

use a `for`, and calculate the parameters for each invocation from the `for` index.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object to store the four points, create a list of the four point object and use a for each loop over the list.
Something like:

```
public class Face {
  private final int a, b, c, d;

  public Face(int a, int b, ....) {
     this.a = a;
     ...
  }

  public int getA() {
    return a;
  }
```

}

This can then be used something like:

```
List<Face> faces = // list of faces, multiple ways to create this.

for (Face face in faces) {
  tekening.drawRect(face.getA(), face.getB(),....
}
```